# Error converting bytecode to dex - Multiple dex files define

Tags: android, gradle, dex

I work on an android application, but during build process I have got following error message. Android Studio has updated Gradle version, maybe this causes errors.

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: 0Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

I have tried to use code after project clean and rebuild in `build.gradle`.

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

After that I get much more error messages, like this.

```
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/animation/AnimatorCompatHelper;
```

Comment: What if you add this to your build.gradle file?

`android {
   defaultConfig {
   ...
   multiDexEnabled = true
   }
}`

Comment: @qantik: It seems same error message.

Comment: Let me dig deeper...

Comment: Can you run `gradle androidDependencies` to see if there are any overlapping dependencies that need to be removed?

Comment: Let me know if it worked out.

Comment: @qantik: I have got another error message:
`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/widget/ExploreByTouchHelper.class`

I haven't found where to run `gradle` command.

Comment: You can run the `gradle` in the terminal when you are in the root directory of the project. First try `gradle clean` then `gradle androidDependencies`.

Comment: @qantik : That is okay, but I'm using Windows and command prompt couldn't recognize this command.

Comment: You can also clean the project inside Android Studio. `Build->Clean Project`.

Comment: I have tried this already, but after rebuild I got same message, that I copied earlier.